# How can I find out from which archive area a Debian package is?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I know I can find out with e.g. `apt-cache policy <PKG>` to which archive a package belongs.

But how can I find out the [archive area](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html), like `main` or `contrib` for an installed package?

I want to be able to tell my friends for example "To install package HotNewStuff, you have to enable the `contrib` section in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `apt` frontend to see that.

```
apt show net-tools                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ⏎ 
Package: net-tools
Version: 1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: net
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: net-tools Team <pkg-net-tools-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 803 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
Conflicts: ja-trans (<= 0.8-2)
Replaces: ja-trans (<= 0.8-2), netbase (<< 4.00)
Homepage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/
Task: dns-server, cloud-image, server, xubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 194 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

From **APT-Sources** you can see that the package has been installed from `bionic/main`.

The command you need is

```
apt show <package>
```

For ease you can use `grep` to filter it:

```
apt show <package> | grep -Po "APT-Sources: \K.*"
```